# Printing numpy.float64 with full precision

Tags: python, numpy

What is the proper/accepted way to print and convert a numpy.float64 to a string?  I've noticed just using `print` or `str()` will lose some precision.  However, `repr` maintains the full precision.  For example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.float64('6374.345407799015')
6374.3454078
>>> print repr(numpy.float64('6374.345407799015'))
6374.3454077990154
```

1. I assume that just calling print turns into calling `str()` on the float64 object.  So is `__str__()` for numpy.float64 implemented with something like `'%s' % (float(self))` or somehow casts the float64 with Python's built-in `float()`?  I tried to quickly look around the numpy source for this but wasn't immediately obvious what was happening.
2. I've always thought `repr()` should return valid Python code that could be used by `eval()` to re-create the object.  Is this an accepted convention?  Luckily in this case numpy does not follow this convention because `repr()` returns just the raw number as a string instead of something like `"numpy.float64('6374.345407799015')"`.

So, all of this confuses me.  What is the correct way to convert a numpy.float64 to a string and/or print it while guaranteeing you always have the same, full precision?

Comment: It's also worth noting that calling `repr()` actually results in MORE precision than the original string that was used to create the float64 object in the first place.  What's the story there?

Comment: In response to your comment, Note that floating point numbers can't represent every number exactly.  In other words, you're asking for the number: `'6374.345407799015'`, but that can't be represented by a float64 number, so numpy (following the IEEE standard) picks the next closest thing which happens to be `6374.3454077990154`.

Comment: Finally, I would say that the best way to turn a `float64` object into a string which is full precision is to use `repr`.  If you look at the python data-model, it recommends that `__repr__` for an object should provide sufficient information to reconstruct the object (if possible).

Comment: @mgilson Ok, thanks for the update.  I understand the reason for the extra precision just because of floating point representations in general.

Comment: @mgilson I can see that `repr()` works and that Python recommends using `__repr__` to reconstruct the object.  However, I always thought it should return valid Python code to actually build the object.  So, by this logic `__repr__` should return a string with the type, like my example above, `"numpy.float64('6374.345407799015')"`.  I'm glad numpy doesn't do this in this particular case.  However, is my understanding of `__repr__` return value incorrect and why?

Comment: I suppose this is a matter of how you interpret the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__).  Specifically, it says that "the string should be a valid python expression which can be used to recreate the object given and appropriate environment if possible".  You're assuming the appropriate environment is `eval`, but it's just as reasonable to assume the environment is `np.float64` IMHO.

Answer (score 12):

The `astype` method works well:

```
>>> numpy.float64('6374.345407799015').astype(str)
'6374.345407799015'
```

Answer (score 10):

Look into [numpy.set_printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html). Specifically,

```
numpy.set_printoptions(precision=15)
```

Comment: You can't see it, but I already posted (and deleted) this answer.  The problem is that this only changes the representation of the values when they are packed into an array.

Comment: Right, I tried this and it does indeed only deal with numpy.ndarray().  This has no effect on a single numpy.float64.  Still good to know though!

Comment: @reptilicus -- I was pretty surprised (and disappointed) when it didn't work.

Comment: is precision=15 sufficient to exactly represent float64 numbers?

Comment: @mgilson It's worse than that.  It only works on arrays having `ndim>1`

Comment: @endolith: if you run [np.finfo(np.float)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html), you should get something like `finfo(resolution=1e-15, min=-1.7976931348623157e+308, max=1.7976931348623157e+308, dtype=float64)`. The `resolution` probably corresponds to the max precision.