# Dealing with numpy arrays lost of precision

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm doing some calculation with numpy arrays and I'm having some problems with precision.
I have a list

```
pop= [[-0.9710937996910745, -3.3798035014183636], [-0.9710937996910731, -3.3798035014183654]]
```

and I try to put into numpy.array

```
X1 = numpy.empty((2), dtype=float64)

for i in range(2):
    X1[i] = pop[i][0]
```

but I get

```
> print(X1)

[[-0.9710938]
 [-0.9710938]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing numpy.float64 with full precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956333/printing-numpy-float64-with-full-precision) or [How to pretty-print a numpy.array without scientific notation and with given precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-print-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given-pre)

Comment: This is just a display difference, not a change in actual precision.  Look at `X1[0,0]`.